# Overwriting auto-appended NOT IN query in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query

When I try to grab bbpress topics AND posts in the same WP_Query, Wordpress automatically appends a NOT IN query to make sure the topics are not in private forum categories.

However since posts don't have forum categories at all, it rules them all out, returning only topics.

How can I overwrite that so it only checks for the forum category on topics, not other post types?

Sample of the MySQL query that is added:

```
WHERE (mt1.meta_key = '_bbp_forum_id' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) NOT IN ('60416','287110','4673','4677'))
```

WP_Query:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array( 'post_type' => array('topic','post', 'video'));
```

Comment: you say forum categories, but the query is a meta query? you'll also have to alter the join if only some posts are selected by meta data.

Comment: If you search for any `pre_get_posts` hooks in the *BBPress* code base, you'll only find this one: 
`add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'bbp_pre_get_posts_normalize_forum_visibility', 4 ); // Always exclude private/hidden forums if needed`. This seems to be responsible for modifying your query. So you might want to remove it before you custom `WP_Query()` and add it again afterwards.

Comment: If you then go on to check out `bbp_pre_get_posts_normalize_forum_visibility()` you will find the interesting line with: `$forum_ids = bbp_exclude_forum_ids( 'meta_query' ); // Get forums to exclude`. You might also want to try out the `bbp_exclude_forum_ids` filter, but now we're getting into a 3rd party plugin support that's pretty much off topic here, so I leave the rest up to you ;-)

Comment: @birgire - This worked! Thank you. Can you submit your answer as a reply so I can give you the bounty?

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. Please feel free to answer it and share what worked for you @JordanLejuwaan